# Changing the style of a progressbar

Tags: android

I have loaded a progressBar from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+android:id/progress_small" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

On different devices I get different visualization. I want the progressbar on every device and every android version look rounded and not being built by some short liney only.

Is there a way to force this?
Thanks so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a custom ProgressBar. Check out [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841231/custom-progressbar-widget).

Also check this examples [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-progressbar-for-android.html), [here](http://sites.google.com/site/learncodesnow/Home/android/progressbar).

This example is without coding: http://majaxandroidtips.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create custom progress bar,

I created a sample project to demonstrate how to skin the Progress bar.
Please take a look at it/

https://github.com/gansBhat/AndroidProjects/tree/master/Examples/CustomThinProgressBar

Same has been uploaded to google drive
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxHClVwHSqq5dVRvT1Qyd0hYN0k&usp=sharing

Let me know if you face some issue.